# How can I sort a table by displayed value rather than internal value?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I am using [ETable](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/etable/ETable.html) for a little bit of added functionality over the standard JTable.

The problem I am facing is in sorting the table correctly when the column headers are clicked. Currently, I have a date field displaying the Modified Julian Date (MJD) in its raw (double) format. Internally, it is an MJD object (which looks like a date string). When the table is sorted, the column treated in the default manner (lexicographical sort) and thus yields a list like `1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 101.0, ...`. If I display the MJD object rather than the double form, it is sorted correctly; however, I need to display it as a double. **How can I force the comparisons and sorting to be done based on what is displayed?**

Note that I have looked at several similar questions posted here like
 [Java JTable Sorting Doesn't Work for Just One Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987885/java-jtable-sorting-doesnt-work-for-just-one-column?lq=1). This type of solution doesn't work for me since I cannot simply return a double class for the column since it is internally a different object type.

Comment: Most of those structures should allow you to provide your own `Comparator` and thus you can define yourself how those strings are compared, i.e. convert them to double and then convert etc.

Comment: @Thomas I'm fairly new to java and I've seen examples of `Comparator` but I'm not really sure where to put it? The MJD class already overrides `compareTo` so that we can compare the actual MJD objects.

Comment: Well in that case your column data type should be `MJD`. AFAIK the table uses a `RowSorter` (set via `table.setRowSorter(...)`) and the default would be an instance of `TableRowSorter` which should correctly work on classed implementing `Comparable`. Besides that you could also try and get the `RowSorter` and call `setComparator(index, comparator)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated in the [`JTable` tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), you can set a `TableRowSorter` on your table or on that specific column. The `DefaultRowSorter#setComparator` is interesting in your case: you can re-use the default row sorter for all your columns, and just specify a custom `Comparator` for that specific column.

Of course, if your objects in the table model already implement `Comparable`, there is no need to set your own `Comparator`. Just make sure that the `TableModel#getColumnClass` returns the correct class.

Comment: From [DefaultRowSorter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html) "If you specify a Comparator that casts its argument to a type other than that provided by the model, a ClassCastException will be thrown when the data is sorted." This is part of my problem. The model expects an MJD type but I want to compare doubles. `getColumnClass` returns an MJD class and that cannot be changed to double for the same reason.